# how to give read premission to a folder using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, security, permissions

i have 2 or more subfolders in my website. And i need to give read-only permission to all my sub-folder for protect from hacking.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with .htaccess, just change the permissions on the concerned directory.

Answer (score 0):

`chmod -R 777` where -R makes it recursive, so all underlying files of that folder will be set to the same permission, 777 in my example.

Comment: how to set it with htaccess

Comment: permissions with .htaccess? o.O

Comment: I don't think there is a way to set permissions using .htaccess.. @vijim

Answer (score 0):

you need to do `chown -R www-data:www-data your-directory-here`
(here, www-data is the default apache username under debian 7)

and then `chmod 711 your-directory-here`.

But there's no way to set permissions using .htacces, it's all or nothing with .htaccess, but the web user is considered as apache, so www-data.

If you don't want users to acces to your directory on apache, simply edit /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default and edit this:

`<Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
</Directory>`

like this:

`<Directory />
                Options -FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Options -Indexes
</Directory>`

Options -Indexes Disallows users to view your directory indexes
Options -FollowSymLinks Disallow apache to follow Symbolic links (don't edit this one if you need apache to follow some symbolic links).

btw, apache folders can't be edited from web client, you need a ssh access for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using FileZilla or a similar FTP client you can right click on anything then use the UI to select permissions regarding every aspect of the file.